# How can I securely alter player data via PHP AJAX call?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, security, md5

While developing a Facebook game, I'm realizing that I can't yet think of a secure way to change user data (like, for example, player health), which I want to do via AJAX calls. If I call a script such as `change_user_health.php` with the parameters `{userid : 12345, newhealth : 25}`, how can I call it in such a way as to prevent users from peeking at the script and calling that script themselves to, say, give themselves full health at all times?

I was originally thinking of passing a hash (perhaps a salted MD5 encryption of a certain value), but this hash would be visible within the JavaScript that calls the AJAX script file. What can I do to call an AJAX PHP script without the user seeing how the MD5 hash is salted and composed? I want the hash to include the health value (25 in the above example) in its composition, so that the user can't just pop in a different value (like 100) with the same hash.

Comment: AJAX security is complicated, but why is it so important for a game? Just wondering.

Comment: If a player is in combat and gets a hit on his health, I'd rather not have the user occasionally cheat and call the AJAX script with a new health value of "100" to renew his health. I don't need perfect security, but enough to deter the average person from cheating.

Comment: I wuold serve a specific code at the load of the game, the server also remembers this code in a player-code dictionary. When making the AJAX call, pass that code and the server will check whether that code is valid. The server then knows who wants to set full health on who. When these persons are the same, refuse the call.

Comment: You could store the users' health in SQL. That could certainly ensure that nobody could cheat with AJAX, and it probably uses SQL already, if it uses AJAX. Also, I agree with Pimvdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution: Make everything server-side.

Say, player get's hit. Instead of doing a request to send set the players HP ( setPlayerHP( current_hp - damage ))

send a request to inform the server that the player has been hit, and let the server handle that and send the remaining hp in the response. ( playerHit() )

The server should then figure out what hit him, and what armor he is wearing. You can't trust javascript at all... If for example you sent the monster id along with the request, or the armor id, then the player could easily forge that.

What you are into sounds like an interesting programming experience :) Lag makes things a lot funnier, too.

Comment: I was going to say much the same thing. You can also make use of obfuscation to make the interface between the JavaScript and PHP hard to follow. Using script and variable names that don't have obvious meanings (or that are intentionally misleading) will make it harder for casual cheaters.

Comment: I was also thinking of having a unique hash value for each NPC enemy in the database. This hash value could be passed as its ID so the player can't just change the ID to something else. If the AJAX-called PHP script can't find the enemy ID (and it's not blank), a hacking attempt is logged and the action is essentially cancelled. -- Do you think this should be sufficient? Telling server to process the hit instead of JS is a great idea.

Comment: The same could be done for, say, when the player purchases items from a vendor. Prices will be stored in the database, so only the item ID and vendor ID are passed. If the player alters the item ID he'll get a different item. I see no way the player could hack the price unless he hacked the database itself. Good idea!

Comment: the hash idea is nice, but i reckon you need a  well tested encryption system - like mcrypt ( hash is one-way only). Still, i could look for the hash/crypt of a lesser monster, and send that instead. You could avoid that, i'm sure, but i can't think of anything right now. Maybe the hash could be mcrypt($monsterid."|".$playerid."|".$mapid) ? then you'd check that everything matches or save a huge log somewhere. :) it's important that you send the encrypted monster codes to the client, and not encrypt them there ( so that the client doesn't have the key )

Comment: Due to the nature of the game I think this can be avoided. (Dunno if you're familiar with EGA Trek, but it's a similar concept. In my game, however, the player can't leave a screen once he's been attacked by enemies. This prevents using previous enemy hashes.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a discussion on techniques you could use to mitigate the problem: [How to Check Authenticity of an AJAX Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017094/how-to-check-authenticity-of-an-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing you can do is see if the request came from an ajax request, such as this:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  // a valid ajax request
} else {
 // not a valid ajax request
```

}

You should now explore:

1. setting a secret hash in a JS variable (and save it in
   a session) when the page is rendered.
2. send that secret hash whenever you
   make an ajax request (POST or GET, whatever you are using).
3. When you process the request, first
   check if the request came from an
   xmlhttprequest, then make sure that
   the key sent with the request equals
   the one set in the session variable.

Good Luck!

Comment: the problem with this, is that you have to add the hash in the javascript, ergo rendering it useless.

Comment: This is a good idea. I wrote down a sample process and wanted to know if this should be sufficient: (1) Upon game load, new "user hash" generated randomly and stored in database and cookie, as well as a client-side JavaScript variable. There are now three places this userhash is stored. (2) Client-side, every 10 sec run a script that checks the userhash from the database and cookie. If they match, update the JS variable. (3) When an AJAX call is made to alter player data, pass the JS userhash variable. (3a) In the PHP script called via AJAX, check POSTed userhash vs. database vs cookie. (cont)

Comment: (cont'd) If all 3 values match, then process the change to the player data, and generate a new random userhash, storing it in the cookie and database. (4) When Step 2 is repeated, since cookie and DB are the same, the JS variable is then updated. // I'm not sure if I'm going too far, or not far enough. What do you think?

Comment: So its basically a good for one change - no matter what change - card? I don't get the point. Is it worth the overhead? If javascript can get the hash, the hacker can get the hash.